# PowerShell string concatenation behaves differently inside vs. outside a function

Tags: string, powershell, string-concatenation

I'm seeing really odd behavior in string concatenation in PowerShell. At first I was using `"$var1: Hello"` syntax for string replacement, but then switched to simple concatenation with `+` because it wasn't working. Now I'm noticing that using the exact same assignment expression, I get two different results.

This feels buggy to me, but I want to make sure I'm not doing something wrong.

```
function Test-Diff([string] $sRepoGUID, [string] $sChangeset1, [string] $sChangeset2){
  $url = $g_backendUrl + "repo/" + $sRepoGUID + "/diff/" + $sChangeset1 + ":" + $sChangeset2 + "?format=json&ignorews=True&maxsize=100000&timeout=10"
  Write-Output $url
}

$g_backendUrl = "http://localhost:56783/"
$sRepoGUID = '34CAA433-1600-469E-95B7-35CA0A0FECF4'
$sChangeset1 = '9d21e91b213a07e56d16a9b8fe519ad570d5c46e'
$sChangeset2 = '68269169cdd0b803d0e419752ce9cae627e589e5'
$url = $g_backendUrl + "repo/" + $sRepoGUID + "/diff/" + $sChangeset1 + ":" + $sChangeset2 + "?format=json&ignorews=True&maxsize=100000&timeout=10" 
Write-Output $url
Test-Diff($sRepoGUID, $sChangeset1, $sChangeset2)
```

That writes the following to the console:

```
http://localhost:56783/repo/34CAA433-1600-469E-95B7-35CA0A0FECF4/diff/9d21e91b213a07e56d16a9b8fe519ad570d5c46e:68269169cdd0b803d0e419752ce9cae627e589e5?format=json&ignorews=True&maxsize=100000&timeout=10
http://localhost:56783/repo/34CAA433-1600-469E-95B7-35CA0A0FECF4 9d21e91b213a07e56d16a9b8fe519ad570d5c46e 68269169cdd0b803d0e419752ce9cae627e589e5/diff/:?format=json&ignorews=True&maxsize=100000&timeout=10
```

Note how the first string contains `/diff/` and `:` in the correct place in the string. The second string has spaces where `/diff/` and `:` should be and instead appends `/diff/` and `:` after the last concatenated variable.

I used the exact same `$url = ...` expression in both places (I even used copy/paste to be sure).

I'm on Windows 7 x64 and have tested this on two different machines.

What might be happening to cause this behavior?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/powershell/info

Comment: This gotcha got me in a big time. Thanks @manojlds

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem is in the way you're passing arguments to your function.  See if this works better:

```
Test-Diff $sRepoGUID $sChangeset1 $sChangeset2
```

Comment: of course! I can't believe I missed that. It's concatenating the values as a single parameter when I use the comma.

Answer (score 5):

Short Answer: `Test-Diff $sRepoGUID $sChangeset1 $sChangeset2` is the correct syntax to pass three parameters.

Long answer: `($sRepoGUID, $sChangeset1, $sChangeset2)` is an array of three elements.  So, when you call `Test-Diff ($sRepoGUID, $sChangeset1, $sChangeset2)`, you're actually calling `Test-Diff` with one parameter that happens to be an array, rather than the three parameters you meant to pass.  So, in the expression

> $g_backendUrl + "repo/" + $sRepoGUID + "/diff/" + $sChangeset1 + ":" + $sChangeset2 + "?format=json&ignorews=True&maxsize=100000&timeout=10"

`$sRepoGUID` is an array, and will be rendered into the string as `34CAA433-1600-469E-95B7-35CA0A0FECF4 9d21e91b213a07e56d16a9b8fe519ad570d5c46e 68269169cdd0b803d0e419752ce9cae627e589e5`, while `$sChangeset1` and `$sChangeset2` are both null, and will not contribute any text to the resulting string.